# How to add PWA functionality to a express web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, progressive-web-apps

I am currently trying to add PWA integration to a web app. I have created a manifest.json and added it to the head of my page, and that is loading fine, however the serviceworker registered in my app.js doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Below is the section of code I am using to set up the app:

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require('path')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const debug = require('debug')('app')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const sql = require('mssql')
const navigator = require('navigator')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname+"/src/views/")
const routesPath = path.join(__dirname+"/src/routes/")
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname+"/public/")
const modulePath = path.join(__dirname+'/node_modules/')
const port = process.env.PORT || 443

const alcoholRouter = require(routesPath+'alcoholRoutes.js')
const cocktailRouter = require(routesPath+'cocktailRoutes.js')
const mixerRouter = require(routesPath+'mixerRoutes.js')

app.use(morgan('tiny'))
app.use(express.static(publicPath))
app.use('/css', express.static(modulePath+'bootstrap\\dist\\css'))
app.use('/js', express.static(modulePath+'bootstrap\\dist\\js'))
app.use('/js', express.static(modulePath+'jquery\\dist'))
app.set('views', viewsPath)
app.set('view engine', process.env.ENGINE || "ejs")
app.use('/alcohol', alcoholRouter)
app.use('/cocktails', cocktailRouter)
app.use('/mixers', mixerRouter)

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        nav:  [
            {link: '/alcohol', title: 'Alcohol'},
            {link: '/cocktails', title: 'Cocktails'},
            {link: '/mixers', title: 'Mixers'}
        ],
        title: 'BarCart'
    })
})

https.createServer(
    {
        key:fs.readFileSync('44400120_localhost.key'),
        cert:fs.readFileSync('44400120_localhost.cert'),
    }, app).listen(port, function(){
        debug(`Listening on port ${chalk.greenBright(port)}`)
    }
)

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
})

app.listen(80)

if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
}
```

This is the code for my serviceworker

```
var contentToCache = [
    './',
    'src/views/alcoholListView.ejs',
    'src/views/cocktailListView.ejs',
    'src/views/mixerListView.ejs',
    'src/views/alcoholView.ejs',
    'src/views/cocktailView.ejs',
    'src/views/mixerView.ejs',
    'src/views/index.ejs',
    'app.js',
    'src/routes/alcoholRoutes.js',
    'src/routes/cocktailRoutes.js',
    'src/routes/mixerRoutes.js',
    'public/css/styles.css'
]
self.addEventListenent('install', function (e) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Install')
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Caching all: app shell and content')
            return cache.addAll(contentToCache)
        })
    )
})
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request).then(function (r) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Caching new resource: ' + e.request.url)
            return r || fetch(e.request).then(function (response){
                return caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
                    console.log('[Service Worker] caching new resource: ' + e.request.url)
                    cache.put(e.request, response.clone())
                    return response
                })
            })
        })
    )
})

self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((keyList)=>{
            return Promise.all(keyList.map((key)=>{
                if(cacheName.indexOf(key)===-1){
                    return caches.delete(key)
                }
            }))
        })
    )
})
```

Any advice into why it doesnt want to recognise this as a pwa would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first part of your code is running on server but service-worker runs on browsers in client side, so `if('serviceWorker' in navigator)` is always false , you should add `if('serviceWorker' in navigator){ navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js') }` in app.js file for client in /public directory

Comment: Would that be in a seperate .js file that i would then link in the html page, so that it ran on the client side?

Comment: this line of code should be in client side scripts, it can be in separate js file or other js file